# Unable to validate my url in Admob for ssv

Tags: firebase, server, admob, admob-rewardedvideoad

I have a firebase function that wait for a post request from Admob for a rewarded video ad verification. When I try to validate my url in adbmob I get error 404, but when i manually try to send a post request to the url, i get a 200 message.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The callback from admob is not a post but a get request. This was the solution.